# MSBuild performance problems after server migration

Tags: performance, msbuild, teamcity, windows-server-2012

We are running TeamCity with 20-ish .Net build configurations. All of them uses MSBuild 4.0. We recently moved one of our build agents from a machine running Windows Server 2008 to a new physical server running Windows Server 2012, and after this migration all the builds are taking almost twice as long time to finish, compared to on the old server! The new server is more powerful than the old server, both in terms of CPU, RAM and Disk. We have been running benchmarks on both servers, all of them confirming that the new server should be more capable than the old one.

According to the build logs it seems that all the stages of the build is slower, so it's not just one of the build steps that are slower.

First thing we did was to check the CPU utilization during builds, and it is suspiciously low! Only 3-6% CPU usage on some of the cores. RAM usage was also very low. Could it be some config for the build agent that is slowing down the builds, and that we have overlooked?

Note: The new server is running as a virtual machine. At first we thought that was the reason, but then that should have been reflected on the benchmarks? This is the only virtual machine running on this physical server, and it has almost all HW resources dedicated. Would be interesting to hear if any of you have had similar bad experience with running the build server on a virtual machine. We have also tried booting "natively" from the VHD image, without any difference in the build times.

I know this could be a very tricky one to debug for "external" people, but I was hoping that someone could maybe give some good suggestion on where to look for the issue, as we are kind of stuck right now.

Edit: Tried activating the Performance Monitor tool in TeamCity, and it shows that both CPU, RAM and Disk usage is comfortably running at <10% (Disk access peaked at 35% a couple of times during the build)

Comment: You need somehow to isolate the issue, just as an idea - create simple fake build with just one target which actually does benchmarking (Exec task for example) and compare results on old / new environments. OR / And compare detailed logs (/v:diag switch) for old / new servers with similar targets which work with different resources - TFS Get (network), Build (CPU / FileSystem / Memory), Publish (File system) etc

Comment: Do you have a Anti-Virus solution installed on the new server? Is it optimized for Windows 2012? Have you excluded the TFS Cache folder, your build agent folder and the drop folder from your anti-virus solution? Also, normally Filo I/O is the single biggest slowdown on a build server. Does your virtual server have a dedicated disk, preferably an SSD?

Comment: Both have good suggestions! Creating a simple dummy build and diffing the logs seems like a good idea. About the antivirus: Yes, it does have antivirus software, but it does have exceptions for the build agent folders. We tried to deactivate the antivirus software,and the build time went down, but only marginally compared to the build time on the old server. The HDD is dedicated 10K RPM raid 1. Should be good enough, I think.

Comment: Msbuild is single threaded by default so that might go someway to explaining CPU utilisation. I'd download the sysinternals tools and get procmon and procexplorer on the go. These should give you a good idea on what's happening on the machine

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution?